# Detect hover in jquery drag event

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm using a `Jquery UI drag/drop` effect, and while i'm dragging the element I need to execute a piece of code that detects if an element is `hovered`.

*Update: Live Example: [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjyLQN?editors=101)*

Here is my Drag code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
      $('.list-disc').sortable({
         connectWith: '.list-disc',

         drag: function(event, ui){
            $(".prof-name").hover(function(event) {
               var $obj = event.target;
               if (!timeoutId) {
                  timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
                  timeoutId = null;
                  $($obj).next().slideToggle();
                  }, 2000);
               }
            },
            function (event) {
            if (timeoutId) {
               window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
               timeoutId = null;
            }
            else {
               $(event.target).next().slideToggle();
            }
         });
         },

        start: function (event, ui){
           //SomeCode
        },
        stop: function (event, ui){
          //SomeCode
        }
        })
</script>
```

The documentation says:

> **drag( event, ui )**
>   Triggered while the mouse is moved during the dragging, immediately before the current move happens.

Maybe I've understood it wrong or something is wrong with the code...
As you can see, I can make that code inside `drag::` event works when executing it inside my `$(document).ready(function(){}`. But I need to do it while draggin the element, test if the dragged element is hover that object for 2 seconds then i'll `slideToggle()` it.

Also tried to write a simple `console.log()` to verify if that's firing, but nothing...

*Update:*Tried Ron's answer:  (Still not working - Nothing happens)

```
over: function(event, ui){
   var timeoutId;
   $(".prof-name").hover(function(event) {
      var $obj = event.target;
      if (!timeoutId) {
         timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
            timeoutId = null;
            $(this).next().slideToggle();
         }, 2000);
      }
   },
   function (event) {
   if (timeoutId) {
      window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      timeoutId = null;
   }
   else {
      $(event.target).next().slideToggle();
   }
   });
}
```

Comment: Could you please post a jsfiddle demo? it will be easier for us to help you that wau

Comment: @Ron of course, updated with codepen live example.

Comment: are you sure the example is correct? I dont see any sortable function in the example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( ".list-disc").sortable({
  over: function( event, ui ) { // $(this) will be the current hovered element }
});
```

Comment: This is not how you were supposed to use it.. you should check inside the over `if $(".prof-name") == $(this)' then do what you want, else it's not on that element. I also recommend you to console.log ($(this)) and see what element it is on when you hover .prof-name, maybe it bubbles to something else